# Java memory management: iOS style memory monitoring?

Tags: java, ios, memory, notifications, jvm

I am very curious that whether in Java there is any way to release the memory as needed - just as the `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` in iOS?

For example, I may have an array used as a caching structure in my program, and when the JVM has memory pressure (heap space is draining), I can get some notification to release some memory by forcing GC and clean the array cache?

Please comment if you think the question is not clear to you~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GC is run automatically when needed, so you don't need a notification for this.

For caches where you want to manually remove entries when the memory is low, you can use [`SoftReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)s. If you hold only a soft reference to a cache entry, the garbage collector will automatically remove entries from the cache if it needs more memory.

There are already quite a few existing cache implementations which handle this for you (its not trivial to get it right), for example in the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library (cf. [`CacheBuilder`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html)).

Comment: +1 just wanted to post a similar answer with softreferences and guava :) for better understanding of java references i found [this article](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.refobj) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Glad to see that this is a well-proved answer (@PhilippWendler @ortang and @mikera)!

Answer (score 2):

In Java you should generally just let the GC handle memory for you.

If you want a cache that will be cleared when there is memory pressure, then you should use one based on **Soft References** (which is a variant of the more general category of [Weak References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference)). If an object is referenced only by soft references, then the GC will clear it up before it runs out of memory.

An easy way to create soft reference caches is with Guava's [CacheBuilder](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the already mentioned SoftReference you can simply register a notification that triggers e.g. at about 95% memory usage:

```
MemoryMXBean mbean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
NotificationBroadcaster emitter = (NotificationBroadcaster) mbean;
emitter.addNotificationListener(new NotificationListener() {
  public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) {
    System.out.println("Low memory notification");
}
}, null, null);
for (MemoryPoolMXBean memPool : ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()) {
  if (memPool.isUsageThresholdSupported()) {
    MemoryUsage memUsage = memPool.getUsage();
    memPool.setUsageThreshold((long) (memUsage.getMax() * 0.95));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert for the answer! I think I will try Guava first, but this is definitely a way.

Answer (score 0):

The Java VM manages the memory by itself.
All you can do is to make a null reference to your cache object and call 
`System.gc()`

Java will then clean the heap space. As far as i know there is nothing more you can do.

Comment: Calling System.gc() doesn't invoke the garbage collector. Rather, it gives the VM a hint that it can do so. Whether it actually chooses to do such it up to it. In general, calling System.gc() is not the answer to your problem, or any problem. Honestly, I've never seen a case where it's actually useful to call it (though I'd love to see one).